# Map BuiltList<String> to BuiltList<Int>

Tags: dart

I have a list of strings in BuiltList, and want to convert them to another BuiltList of int values.

```
final lengths = BuiltList<String>(['a', 'bbbb', 'cdea']).rebuild((b) =>
  b.map((e) => e.length)
);
```

When using map in the builder, Dart Analysis says "error: The return type 'int' isn't a 'String', as defined by anonymous closure.".

How can I map from String to Int using the built_collection library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rebuild` is to update a built value https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/built_value/latest/built_value/Built/rebuild.html

You want a different list:

```
final strings = BuiltList<String>(['a', 'bbbb', 'cdea']);
final lengths = BuiltList<int>(string.map((e) => e.length));
```